# Neo4j .NET Client Wrap transactions

Tags: neo4jclient

Is it possible to wrap several transactions as one using NEO4J client .NET? My problem is that I need to delete one node, all relationships and all END nodes attached to these relationships as one ACID transaction. I understand that using REST batch is possible. Can I do it with NEO4j .NET Client?

Thank you so much for your support!

Answer (score 2):

Do it all in a single Cypher call:

```
START n=node(123)
MATCH n-[r]->m
DELETE r, m, n
```

In C#:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Start(new { n = (NodeReference)123 })
    .Match("n-[r]->m")
    .Delete("r, m, n")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

Transaction support will come when Neo4j 2.0, Cypher, and [this update](https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/91/support-cypher-transactions-integrated) to Neo4jClient all align.